# Blank Page after implementing visualization of Google API?

Tags: javascript, html

I've used both **safari and google chrome as web browser both of them are showing blank page**. But when I wrote a paragraph in html file it's showing the **paragraph only**, but not the javascript part. I have named my javascript file as map.js.

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="map.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['geochart', 'corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawRegionsMap() {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Customer Count', 'Agent Count'],
          ['Argentina', 999000, 100],
          ['Australia', 969000, 450],
          ['Belgium', 12000, 200],
          ['Brazil', 850000, 250],
          ['Canada', 1110000, 590],
          ['China', 3975000, 690],
          ['Colombia', 4500, 100],
          ['Denmark', 78600, 150],
          ['France', 67000, 400],
          ['Germany', 140000, 550],
          ['India', 1060000, 560],
          ['Japan', 60000, 420],
          ['Nigeria', 1054000, 305],
          ['Philippines', 120000, 230],
          ['Russia', 2904000, 180],
          ['Singapore', 79000, 450],
          ['South Korea', 15000, 290],
          ['Switzerland', 35000, 230],
          ['United Kingdom', 4015000, 750],
          ['United States', 5000500, 1500],
]);

var options = {
colorAxis: {colors: ['#eee8f3', '#ddd1e7','#ccbadc','#bba3d0','#aa8cc5','#9975b9','#885ead', '#7647a2', '#663096', '#551a8b']},
legend: 'none',
};

var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascrip is a logic running behind the html page. Javascript doesn't render (or show) on the page. It can manipulate the html elements already existing on the page, or add new elements if instructed.

Try starting with simple example and tutorials https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp to learn HTML and https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp to learn javascript.

Comment: @Soumya I updated the answer. Run the snippet it still gives an error "drawChart" undefined. Where is that function located ?

Comment: @Soumya Yes because you need to define the callback function drawChart. See the error it is giving : "drawChart" undefined. You are passing an undefined function as a callback parameter

Comment: I deleted that line and the var chart line also then also it is giving blank page.

Comment: @Soumya Updated the answer. Maybe the issue is misunderstanding of relation between javascript and html. Try starting with maybe simple examples of javascript html tutorials